# how can I extract a region from the google map with R?

Tags: r, google-maps

When I write a name of administrative region (neigbour) to google map it shows the boundries of the region. Which can be seen from : 
[https://www.google.com.tr/maps/place/Atatürk+Mahallesi,+45215+Akhisar%2FManisa/@38.910799,27.7995369,3278m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x14b9ce021b62e939:0x9b2718a9f0234be8!8m2!3d38.9129396!4d27.8106269](https://www.google.com.tr/maps/place/Atat%C3%BCrk+Mahallesi,+45215+Akhisar%2FManisa/@38.910799,27.7995369,3278m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x14b9ce021b62e939:0x9b2718a9f0234be8!8m2!3d38.9129396!4d27.8106269)

My question is is it possible to extract bounded region with R ?

Note: My aim is to calculate the area of the region by counting the number of pixels from the photo. Any other solution is also welcome.

Comment: Can you please explain better your objective?

Comment: Are you doing this for just one region?

Comment: @Seymour If I can extract the region which is shown as red in the link, i will count the number of pixels in order to obtain the region of the area.

Comment: @symbolixAU I need to do this for too many region.

Comment: @SymbolixAU The saver! You packages are so useful!!!

Comment: Google Maps doesn't return the region through their API. If you only have a handful of regions you could manually draw the boundaries through `googleway` and `shiny`. This will give you the coordinates of the boundaries which you can then use to calculate the area. Alternatively, as @Seymour indicates you should try to find a shape file of the boundaries you're interested in.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I dont think exists any shapefile at the granular level of neighborhood. Is there any other approach?

Comment: @Seymour Well if ı can find a way to take screen shots of all the regions that would also work. The only package ı found for this aim is "webshot". However The browser it uses is not supported by google map so it cant show the red region in the map. Do you know any other alternative to take screen shots automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a way to get the boundary of a neighborhood.

However, if your goal is to compute the area of a region, you can follow the next steps.

First of all, obtain the open data from [GADM website](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html)
Here select R (sp) level2. It will download a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` of Turkey administrative regions at the finest granular level available.

Then, `require("sp")` which enables you to load the GADM map into a R `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

Next, with a simple `readRDS()` read the file into `R`.

```
your_GADM_file <- readRDS("gadm36_TUR_2_sp.rds")
```

Next, let's get the polygon you are interested in:

```
polygons <- your_GADM_file[your_GADM_file@data$NAME_1 == "Manisa" &
                                   your_GADM_file@data$NAME_2 == "Akhisar", ]
```

Compute area of the polygon:

```
require(raster)
area(raster(your_GADM_file))
```

Comment: Hi Seymour,
Thank you for the answer but what ı need is a little different. Your answer gives me area of a district (Akhisar). However I'm searching for the area of a smaller region ( a neighbor) of districts. In other words, it is not Akhisar/Manisa, it is Atatürk Mahallesi/ Akhisar / Manisa.

Comment: Yes I know, I just decided to share the methodology to accomplish the task of computing area of a polygon. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any automated way to obtain boundaries of neighborhood from Google Maps searches. It seems quite tricky...